# Push notification for my text app for iPhone and Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am building an android and iPhone app that involves sending text messages from within the app. The messages have to be `push messages` since I want them to be delivered even when the app is not running in the foreground.

I know that there are services like [PushWoosh](https://cp.pushwoosh.com/applications) and [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) that let one push a text message (a nativet text message) to someone's phone. But, I am trying to push message to my own app (rather than the native text app). Can someone recommend me how I can implement this for my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

[Here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) is a getting started guide.

Comment: GCM might only work for Android. I am looking for a platform for both iPhone and Android.

Comment: I use two different platforms (GCM for Android and APN for iOS). I have a notification handler that routes the notification for the correct service. You can have a look to Amazon's SNS service? It may do the trick for your needs. Here is the [link](http://aws.amazon.com/es/sns/).